# Magento 2.2 product collection doesn't return out of stock products

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, collection, product-collection, magento2.2

Magento 2.2.* seems to make it very difficult to get out of stock products in a collection! I have the following code which works fine in Magento 2.0 and 2.1:

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
}

public function execute()
{
    // should get ALL products including out of stock ones
    $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create();
```

Now testing it on Magento 2.2.1 and 2.2.2, and it is only retrieving products which are in stock - does anyone know a way to work around this?

I have looked at the internal code for collections and can't find any obvious differences - Any info much appreciated as this is a very irritating change that they've made!

Comment: I have  check the code and it is working ...Are u sure that you have tried default magento 2.2.X vewrsion

Comment: @AmitBera  I have tested in magento 2.2.2 and it is not working for me also. Query for $collection->load() is "SELECT `e`.*, `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1 WHERE (stock_status_index.stock_status = 1)"

Comment: I've the same issue here, did you makes  it work?

Comment: I switched to using an instance of Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface to load each product in the loop, loading it by the entity id of the collection member, rather than accessing the collection members directly - it seems to work now. Accessing the collection members directly seemed to skip over the out of stock products.

Answer (score 0):

Here magento2 added this. Feel free to change it

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection">
        <plugin name="add_stock_information" type="Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\AddStockStatusToCollection" />
    </type>
```

You can always disable it in your di.xml using this

`plugin disabled`: To disable a plugin, set this element to `true`. The default value is `false`.
Use this property to disable core or third-party plugins in your `di.xml` file.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#declaring-a-plugin

Here is the file

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/AddStockStatusToCollection.php.
```

You can override and remove that.

### EDIT

Even better there is a config option in magento 2.2

> configuration->catalog->inventory->Display out of stock products